# SQL query for two table relation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

I have two tables like below;

[image]

and I want the output is something like below;

[image]

I used the SQL query code below

[image]

```
select table2.StatusName as StatusName, count(table1.Status) as NoOfStatus from testingdb.table1, testingdb.table2 where table1.Status=table2.Status group by table1.Status;
```

Anyone can help me in SQL, how to create SQL code to get the result as output.
Really appreciate..

Thanks you very much.

Comment: You forgot to tell us how you get to this output. Take all A and B and count? If you are able to tell us the rules to get that result, maybe you'll be able to tell the DBMS, too. Have you tried anything? If so, what do you have and where have you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

To get your exact output where you group the status names together and count how many are present in that status, and then return the sum of all `NoOfProgress` you could do the following:

```
WITH StatusCheck AS 
(
    SELECT 
        status AS 'statusname',
        COUNT(status) AS 'NoOfProgress'
    FROM TABLE A
    GROUP BY status
)

SELECT 
    x.statusname,
    x.NoOfProgress
FROM StatusCheck x

UNION

SELECT
    '' AS 'statusname',
    SUM(x.NoOfProgress)
FROM StatusCheck x
```

If you need to only look at `A` and `B` specifically, you could just throw in a WHERE clause inside the CTE `StatusCheck`:

```
WITH StatusCheck AS 
(
    SELECT 
        status AS 'statusname',
        COUNT(status) AS 'NoOfProgress'
    FROM TABLE A
    WHERE status IN ('A', 'B')
    GROUP BY status
)
```

Comment: I used mySQL 6.3.3 version and there seem not supported "WITH" statement. I used SQL query below, but it does not solved the problem, i used the sql query ->  

"select table2.StatusName as StatusName, count(table1.Status) as NoOfStatus from testingdb.table1, testingdb.table2 
where table1.Status=table2.Status
group by table1.Status;"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I primarily use TSQL but from what I know of MySQL you should be able to create a CTE using a WITH statement, according to the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). I'd recommend taking a look at that page and seeing if you can get that to work with your query--hope that helps.